# Week Input Value is Not Being Passed to Controller Method in Laravel Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, chart.js

```html
<input type="week" class="week-picker" id="week_input" name="week_input" onchange="SubmitForm(event);" />
```

Below is ajax code:

```js
 function SubmitForm(event) {
            // Prevent form from being submitted normally
            event.preventDefault();

            // Send AJAX request to server to fetch chart data
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/calorie_tracker_weekly',
                data: $('#calorieBarChartWeekly').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    ShowChart(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller method:

```php
public function calorieTrackerWeekly(Request $request)
    {
       $date = $request->input('week_input');
       // Rest of the code
    }
```

Why the controller is not getting the week value?

I've to show calorie tracker weekly bar chart using Chart.js, but it disappears after route finishes loading if I pass the week value to controller using following code:

```html
<form action="{{ route('calorietracker/weekly') }}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   {{-- format of week value is "2023-W09" --}}
   <input type="week" class="week-picker" id="week_input" name="week_date" onchange="return SubmitForm(this.form);" />
</form>
```

The route is:

```php
Route::get('/calorie_tracker_weekly', [UserController::class, 'calorieTrackerWeekly'])->name('calorietracker/weekly');
```

So, to prevent chart from disappearing, I used the ajax, with ajax it didn't disappear but the week value is not passed to controller.

Comment: Your form input has name="week_date" and not "week_input"

Comment: That's of previous code when I didn't use ajax and the chart was disappearing.

Comment: Double-check the AJAX request being made from your JavaScript code. Ensure that the data property includes the correct key-value pair for the week input. For example:
`$.ajax({
    // Other AJAX properties...
    data: {
        week: $('#week-input').val(),
        // Other data properties...
    },
    // Other AJAX configurations...
});`
Verify that the week input field has the correct ID (week_input in this example) and that it contains the desired value.